# Why can BluetoothGattService contain other services?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to understand how BLE works on Android. I have a working version of an app that scans for available BLE devices and connects to a selected one.

I am first scanning for the available BLE devices and check their available services in the ScanCallback:

```
override fun onBatchScanResult(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
        if (results != null) {
           val iterator = results.listIterator()
           for (result in iterator) {
             val scanRecord: ScanRecord? = result.scanRecord

             val uuids = scanRecord?.serviceUuids
             Log.i("Debug", "Found address = " + result.device.address)
             Log.i("Debug", "Found " + uuids?.size + " uuids")
           }
        }

}
```

This always shows me one single service.

Moving on to when I try to connect to a device: In the BluetoothGattCallback -> onServicesDiscovered() I can get a reference to the device's available services and characteristics for each service like in the code below. The callback has a reference to the device I am trying to connect to:

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)

        // break if there was a problem
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i("Debug", "Connection not successful, status = $status")
            return
        }

        Log.i("Debug", "Attempting to connect to " + deviceInfo.uuid)
        val serviceUuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(deviceInfo.uuid.toByteArray())

        val services = gatt?.services
        val characteristics = service?.characteristics

        Log.i("Debug", "Services = " + services.toString())
        if (services != null) {
            for (i in 0..services.size - 1) {
                Log.i("Debug", "Service $i = " + services[i].uuid.toString())

                val chars = services[i].characteristics
                for (j in 0..chars.size - 1) {
                    Log.i("Debug", "Char $j = " + chars[j].uuid.toString())
                }
            }
        }
```

Accessing the service UUIDs this way gives me a list of services for the discovered devices, which is always longer than one element. So it seems that more services are made available once I connect to a device.

My question is **why is this happening**? I thought a profile had multiple services, which in turn have multiple characteristics. But in the onServicesDiscovered() function, calling gatt.services returns a MutableList of BluetoothGattService objects, which, according to the documentation, can contain a list of included services itself. That is very confusing as it does not seem to match the generat GATT profile structure. Furthermore, I don't understand why the initial scan just gives one available service, but connecting to a device uncovers other services.

Comment: When scanning you only get the services that are part the advertisement packet. Typically this will only include 1 or 2 service UUIDs. There is no space for more service UUIDs in the advertisement packet. Once you connect and call discoverServices(), Android will discover ALL services/characteristics/descriptors....

Comment: Hi Martijn thanks for the clarification. I have a further question, though - the advertised service UUID does not match andy of the service UUIDs in discoverServices. Some of them are similar but they differ by one character. E.g. in the advertisement I get "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", but in when discovering services I get the first 8 bytes as "00001800" and "00001801".